# NodeJS connect to MQTT server with credentials and SSL

Tags: node.js, mqtt

I'm trying to connect to an MQTT server with NodeJS, but it's not connecting at all.  This is the code that I'm using:

```
const mqtt = require('mqtt');
function Connect(serverName,serverUsername,serverPassword,port,topic,clientName) {
  try{
  //const client = new mqtt.connect('mqtt://'+serverName);
  const client = new mqtt.connect('mqtts://'+serverName,{rejectUnauthorized:false,username:serverUsername,password:serverPassword,connectTimeout:5000});
  console.log('--connecting');
  client.on('connect',function(){
    console.log('--connected');
    client.subscribe(topic,function(err){
      console.log('--subscribed');
      if (!err) {
        client.publish(topic,"hello 2");
      }
    });
  });

  client.on('message',function(tp,msg){
    console.log(msg.toString());
    client.end();
  });

  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
Connect('mqtt.example.com','myusername','mypassword',9101,'test','NodeApp');
```

When I run the code above, none of the `console.log` statements inside the `client.subscribe` fires.  I tested my MQTT server with these commands and all my subscriptions and published messages work fine:

```
mosquitto_sub -h mqtt.example.com -p 9101 -t "test" -u "myusername" -P "mypassword" --capath /etc/ssl/certs/

mosquitto_pub -h mqtt.example.com -p 9101 -t "test" -m "This is my message" -u "myusername" -P "mypassword" --capath /etc/ssl/certs/
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using mqtts:// but have not defined your SSL certs in the options part of the connect:

```
var caFile = fs.readFileSync("myCAFile");
var certFile = fs.readFileSync("myCertFile");
var keyFile = fs.readFileSync("myKeyFile");

var opts = {
  rejectUnauthorized: false,
  username: serverUsername,
  password: serverPassword,
  connectTimeout: 5000,
  ca: [ caFile ],
  cert: certFile,
  key: keyFile
}

const client = new mqtt.connect('mqtts://'+serverName, opts);
...
```

For the mqtt module, you have to provide the SSL certs, even it its just self-generated ones.

Although you should be catching the error(s)...what does the MQTT Broker log files say?